# How can I set lineItem data payload in shopware6 using html inputs

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

i'm using some inputs to create a cart line item:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ id }}][id]" value="{{ id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ id }}][type]" value="product">
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ id }}][quantity]" value="1">
```

how can I set the payload to this to use with getPayload() or getPayloadValue() in cart collector/processor because using

```
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ id }}][payload][key]" value="value">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="lineItems[{{ id }}][payloadData]" value="value">
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The payload of line items [is not fed by request parameters](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/32e8e5f2c81a0f5540d0a36433e8b48a5735784c/src/Core/Content/Product/Cart/ProductCartProcessor.php#L355) by default.

One possible approach would be to decorate the `CartItemAddRoute` and inject `RequestStack` to set the payload from the request parameters. You'll need to create a plugin to do so.

Service definition:

```xml
<service id="My\Plugin\Decorator\CartItemAddRouteDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartItemAddRoute">
    <argument type="service" id="My\Plugin\Decorator\CartItemAddRouteDecorator.inner"/>
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
</service>
```

Decorator:

```php
class CartItemAddRouteDecorator extends AbstractCartItemAddRoute
{
    private AbstractCartItemAddRoute $decorated;

    private RequestStack $requestStack;

    public function __construct(
        AbstractCartItemAddRoute $decorated,
        RequestStack $requestStack
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractCartItemAddRoute
    {
        return $this->decorated;
    }

    /**
     * @param array<LineItem>|null $items
     */
    public function add(Request $request, Cart $cart, SalesChannelContext $context, ?array $items): CartResponse
    {
        $params = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->request->all();

        if ($items) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if (empty($params['lineItems'][$item->getReferencedId()]['payload']['myKey'])) {
                    continue;
                }

                $item->setPayloadValue(
                    'myKey',
                    $params['lineItems'][$item->getReferencedId()]['payload']['myKey']
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->getDecorated()->add($request, $cart, $context, $items);
    }
}
```

Template:

```html
<input type="text" name="lineItems[{{ product.id }}][payload][myKey]" />
```

Comment: The twig template doesn't work anymore since Shopware 6.5.4.0. You will get this error:

mb_strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\RequestDataBag given

You need to pass the values as a string and not as payload anymore, see also https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/e501c5a56f37b2c7db66510bf4a7fd535a95fccc